# Force All vBulletin Sessions to Logout

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, vbulletin

I am currently building a mobile app that will use an existing vBulletin install as a login system. I've run into an issue where if a user is already signed on somewhere else, they cannot sign back on using the application. On the vBulletin site, if this happens, you are presented with a "Force Logout" button that will end all existing login sessions and allow you to login again.

Is there a way to implement such a feature use just the API? I cannot query the database, unfortunately, and my only means of accessing the vBulletin system is through api.php methods. The vBulletin API documentation is woefully incomplete, so I am hoping someone else would have an answer for this.

If it helps at all, I am using Flex and AS3 to build the application and have successful login and logout, but the logout only works if you pass an appropriate sessionHash to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with our specific vBulletin config. We had to write a custom script that would allow us to access the forcelogout.php page/script and force a logout.